# Imported Javascript function not defined when called from html

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5, webpack, vuejs2

I'm learning laravel 5.5 and VueJs, my issue is when I export some functions from a js file and import it from a second js file it cannot be called from html body. Example:

A.js

```
function funA(){
}
export {funA};
```

B.js

```
import {funA} from './A.js';
```

At this point if I use the function `funA` inside the B.js it works, however if I use it on a html page it says funA is not defined. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <button onClick="funA()"></button>
  <script src="{{asset('js/B.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My webpack configuration is something like this:

```
mix.scripts('resources/assets/js/libs/materialize.js', 'public/js/libs/materialize.js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/A.js', 'public/js/js/A.js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/B.js', 'public/js/B.js');
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your HTML expects the `funA` to be on the global `window` object. The new JavaScript module system doesn't add anything to the global namespace, to avoid namespace pollution.

If you just want to use is anyways on the button then, doing the below should get you working.

```
window.funA = funA
```

You can do this in your `B.js`. Though, I will not recommend this, as I see that you seem to be using Vue and there are better ways to do it. Let me know if this works, also try sharing your Vue code so that someone can help you do it the right way.

Comment: Thank you this really worked, I know with `Vuejs` there are other ways to do it, however the `A.js` contains a lot of helper functions that I use in the whole system, and I need it to be independent from `VueJs`. Again thank you.

Comment: You might try setting the functions on your root vue instance.